# sending a Numpy array to Arduino via serial?

Tags: python, numpy, arduino, serial-port

I'm trying to send a Numpy arrays of floats (every array has 3 members) like:

```
[-1.73921636 -0.47675802 -0.2068679 ]
```

to arduino via serial port.

it looks like that I know so little to solve this problem! I'm using these lines of code in **Python:**

```
import serial
arduino=serial.Serial('com4',9600)

while 1:  
     array = function(x,y,z);
     data=bytearray(array)
     arduino.write(data)
     time.sleep(.5)
```

of course I can't use Arduino serial monitor, So I use a 16x2 LCD to see what I'm exactly receiving from python. All I see is random charachters (often japanese!) I think problem it with decoding numpy array because I can see the string if I put it in `arduino.write(data)`.

**Arduino** code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

char inputBuffer[32];

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin();
  lcd.backlight();
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {

    lcd.clear();
    delay(200);

    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      //lcd.print("                ");
      Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', inputBuffer, 32);
      //Serial.read();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print(inputBuffer);
      memset(inputBuffer, 0, sizeof(inputBuffer));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the communication itself is working just fine. The problem should be because of what you do with the data after you've received it. Can you provide the Arduino code and the way it communicates with the LCD? Event a schema of the LCD&Arduino connection will be great.

Comment: yes,it works. if I put a string in arduino.write() i can see it on my lcd. problem is with decoding i think... which i know almost nothing about it.

Comment: You can convert a numpy array to a string using 'array.tostring()'. To convert the values back to floats you will need to learn how to unpack IEEE floats/doubles. There may be something native on the Arduino, but you can find some code to do that here: http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/pack2b.c.

Comment: @ user545424  i tried 'np.array2string()' . didn't work. error: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `bytearray` in python, it converts the numpy array to an array of bytes. For example, `data = bytearray(np.array([-1.73921636, -0.47675802, -0.2068679]))` gives you a byte array with 24 elements (each element in the numpy array is a double which is 8 bytes each).

When you read this on the Arduino, you need to convert this array of bytes into doubles again before doing any useful operation. `union` would be useful for this. I do not have an LCD to verify this, but something similar should correctly read the bytes as a double.

```
unsigned char inputBuffer[32];

union {float f; unsigned char b[8];} num1;
union {float f; unsigned char b[8];} num2;
union {float f; unsigned char b[8];} num3;

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {

        lcd.clear();
        delay(200);

        if (Serial.available() > 0) {
            Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', inputBuffer, 32);

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                num1.b[i] = inputBuffer[i];
                num2.b[i] = inputBuffer[8 + i];
                num3.b[i] = inputBuffer[16 + i];
            }

        // you can call the read float numbers using num1.f, num2.f, ...
        // other operations to write to the LCD go here
    }
}
```

Also, you might want to consider sending [CRC checksum](https://github.com/bakercp/CRC32) at the end of the message to be safe. When you send a stream of bytes, loosing one byte can lead to really weird numbers.

Comment: with bytearray all I see is japanese... if I use  data=np.array2string(array)  I see Numbers! but I can't separate and extract my 3 numbers. can you help me?

Comment: What is you endian-ness? If you are not sure what that is, try printing all the byte in the variable data in the Python code. Also, convert the first value in the array using [this](http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_double.html) double to hex converter. Compare the first 8 bytes of the Python code with the result you get from the online converter.

Comment: I had never heard of endians... Thank you .

Comment: If the bytes show up in the reverse order, you need to reverse the order you read from on the Arduino. That is `(int i = 7; i > -1; i--)` instead of `(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)` in the `for` loop.

Comment: That's right,  they did show up in reverse order...  thank you again.

Comment: where can I find everything about this stuff? Is there a book that explains about CRC , endian-ness and serial communication for Arduino in general ?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not know a book or any good resource for that. A quick Google search did not give anything useful either. I learnt them through a few years of experience. By the way, if the communication is not that fast (~10 Hz or something), you can just send the string and read the whole string from the Arduino using [`Serial.readStringUntil()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readstringuntil/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193885/discussion-between-2012user-and-kani).